# array as parameter of a function

Tags: c, winapi, function, pointers

There is a array of structures.

```
    static field fields[xsize][ysize];
```

I want to change it in function

```
    void MoveLeft(pacman *Pacman, field **fields,int **play)
```

But when I send it like this

```
     MoveLeft(&Pacman,fields,play);
```

I've got an error.

field - structure

```
     typedef struct
     {
    blossom blossoms;
    wall walls;
     }field;
```

where blossom & wall - another structures

Comment: You got an error... cool :) what error?

Comment: Exactly, what error? PS. I am not sure, I am not really a c programmer, but you send a Pacman reference, while it expects a pointer...

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to indicate in your function prototype that `**fields` is a double pointer, since it's already of type `field`.

Comment: @MichalB.: `&Pacman` is a pointer, and C does not have reference types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although arrays and pointers are somewhat interchangeable in C, they're not exactly the same.  In particular, an array of arrays and an array of pointers are laid out differently in memory.

Here's a way to make an array of pointers which refers to the same data as your existing array of arrays:

```
field* field_rows[xsize];
for (unsigned int i=0; i<xsize; i++) {
    field_rows[i] = fields[i];
}
```

Then a pointer to that `field_rows` array can be passed to `MoveLeft`:

```
MoveLeft(&Pacman,field_rows,play);
```

Another solution might be to change the declaration of `MoveLeft` instead, to take a pointer to array of arrays:

```
void MoveLeft(pacman *Pacman, field fields[xsize][ysize], int **play);

MoveLeft(&Pacman,fields,play);
```

Comment: Now I've got this error
`Unhandled exception at 0x001f100e in pacma.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000044`.
It's error for last method

Comment: That sounds like a different problem.  You'd have to debug the program.

Comment: I've solve this problem. My array play[11][31] in levelinfo.h. So I simple include levelinfo.h in moveprocs.h(where fucntion moveleft is) and it works normal now

Answer (score 2):

I guess the error is the following: two dimension array `fields[xsize][ysize]` is fixed size array (xsize/ysize are defines or consts) and in memory this is not look like `field**`, cause it's pointer to pointer to field, while `fields[xsize][ysize]` internally just one dimension fixed size array, where compiler handle double indexing for you.

**So what you need is just define fields as `field**` and allocate it dynamically.**

See picture for more explanation:
[image]

Comment: This is wrong. `field**` means pointer to pointer to `field`. "pointer to array of pointers to `field`" would be `field *(*fields)[]`. `field**` is a good type to represent the array. It's just that the type conversion has to be done explicitly as pointed out by Joachim Pileborg.

Comment: Ok, to not confuse with terminology let's say that it's pointer to pointer. Internally they all are pointers to buffer of some types...

Comment: @undur_gongor IMHO you are wrong. A `field[][N]` and a `*(field[N])` has the same memory layout. A `field**` and a `(*field)[]` as well, but different than the first one.

Comment: @glglgl: Yes, I am totally wrong (with the last 2 sentences). Sorry. Finally, aschepler got it right.

Answer (score -1):

While I'm not using Windows, I'm guessing your error is something similar to this:

```
error: cannot convert ‘field (*)[xx]’ to ‘field**’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void MoveLeft(pacman*, field**,int**)’
```

A solution to this is to simply cast the `fields` parameter to the type the function wants:

```
MoveLeft(&Pacman, (field **) fields, play);
```

Comment: Right error, but terrible answer; never just "cast away the problem" - all you are doing here is ignoring the error, and telling the compiler to proceed regardless. fields, as defined as [][], is a contiguous 2D array, whereas field** is a pointer to a (implied array) of pointers. The two have very different memory layout; you can't just treat one as the other. If you do, you'll attempt to treat the actual field in the array as through it were actually pointers - if you're lucky you'll get a crash early and realize there's something wrong.