# Easiest way to access a multidimensional arrays using a pointer in C

Tags: c

Let's say I have 2 2-dimensional arrays:

```
int a1[][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} };
int a2[][2] = { {7,8}, {9,0}, {1,1} };
```

and a pointer:

```
int *a;
```

The pointer will point to one of the arrays and at some point point to the other (back and forth). After each reassignment of the pointer I want to read from the array, what is the easiest way to do that?

I can achieve what I want using the following way:

```
a = (int *)a1;
printf("D: %d\n", (int)(*a)+(x*2)+(y)));
a = (int *)a2;
printf("D: %d\n", (int)(*a)+(x*2)+(y)));
```

Output (assuming `x = 0` and `y = 1`):

```
D: 2
D: 8
```

Is there another easier way to access the arrays I.e. by using the standard `[]` operator? If not, then how would you make this more "beautiful"... would you create a macro or a function or what would be the preferred way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `[]` if you always have pairs and turn the pointer to

```
int (*a)[2];
```

This should make it possible to write

```
a = a1;
printf("D: %d\n", a[x][y]);
```

Comment: +1, yes exactly, just access the array with a pointer to its first element. This is how it is meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is wrong:

```
a = (int *)a1;
```

`a1` is a double pointer, as it is an array of `int` arrays, whereas `a` is a pointer to an `int`.

To access individual array values, you can use the [] operator as follows:

```
int a1[][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} };
assert( 2 == a[0][1] );
assert( 4 == a[1][1] );
```

Comment: a1 is not a double pointer. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122225/array-as-parameter-of-a-function/8122289#8122289) for visualization of the both situations.

Comment: @glglgl is that guaranteed by the standard, or just that answer? I don't believe any memory management issues are discussed in the standard - i.e. how arrays of arrays and arrays of pointers should look in memory.

Comment: I think it is, although I don't have a copy of the standard here. If you have "real" 2D arrays, they are arranged in rows and columns. If you have arrays of pointers, you need one or more levels of dereferencing.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I think it is guaranteed by the standard. If you define `int *ptr = malloc(20 * sizeof(int))`, you get 4 for `sizeof(ptr)` (assuming pointer is 4 bytes wide). But if you define `int arr[20]`, you get 80 for `sizeof(arr)` (assuming int is 4 bytes wide). To achieve this, `arr` must be an array, not a pointer.

Comment: @glglgl, yes the standard guarantees that arrays are always layed out consecutively. A 2D is nothing than an array of arrays, so yes it must be layed out consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

Using a table of [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) you could write

```
*(a+x*2+y)
```

by omiting superflous parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Not so nice, but one way to do it:

```
            int a1[][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} };
            int a2[][2] = { {7,8}, {9,0}, {1,1} };

            int (*a)[][2];

            a = &a1;
            printf("value = %d \n", (*a)[x][y] );

            a = &a2;
            printf("value = %d \n", (*a)[x][y] );
```